# Additional css is adding extra spacing on div

Tags: css

I currently have the following code:

```
    <div id="img_preview_text_container" style="width: 376px; height: 75px; top: 156px; left: 50px; color: rgb(255, 0, 0);">
  <div id="customOnePreviewText" style="font-family: Oklahoma; width: 376px; height: 75px;">FABO</div>
</div>
```

Css is like so:

```
#customOnePreviewText {
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
}

#img_preview_text_container {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

This gives me some type that looks fine.
I need to dynamically fit this type into a container.  Type always changes so I run some code called [text fit js](https://github.com/STRML/textFit)

after I run this js method the html code is now this:

```
        <div id="img_preview_text_container" style="width: 376px; height: 75px; top: 156px; left: 50px; color: rgb(255, 0, 0);">
  <div id="customOnePreviewText" style="font-family: Oklahoma; width: 376px; height: 75px; text-align: center; white-space: nowrap;">
    <span class="textFitted" style="display: inline-block; text-align: center; font-size: 80px;">FABO</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

I now get this [image]

The text is no longer centered and the type now has an additional space below.  This wasn't the case BEFORE I ran this textFit.js what can I change to eliminate that extra spacing and also get it to center?

Comment: The `=` in your HTML doesn't make any sense and is invalid. Fix that.

Comment: Fixed, I hope removing the mistaken = now makes sense for you.  @Rob

Comment: I fail to see how this is a downvote question.  It's a real question and falls under SO guidelines.

Comment: Another observation: your HTML is still invalid. A `<span>` cannot contain a `<div>`. Any "fixes" given as answers might not be of any value until you fix that, too, but I haven't looked into that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try add line-height:1 in #customOnePreviewText

```
<div id="customOnePreviewText" style="font-family: Oklahoma; width: 376px;line-height:1;">FABO</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's the height attribute of your id="img_preview_text_container" outer container. set that to a lower value or 0 or 'auto'.